# is there a way to import a Python egg from memory, but not the disk?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a binary string which contains a Python egg, all zipped up. Is there a way to execute and "import" that egg from memory, without ever writing it to disk?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python, import string of Python code as module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614537/python-import-string-of-python-code-as-module)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some time ago I had a look at pypiserver and might be something similar to what you need:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver/0.5.0

The standalone version
https://raw.github.com/schmir/pypiserver/standalone/pypi-server-standalone.py

does some interesting magic with a DictImporter and the zlib library, maybe you can do something similar..

Answer (score 2):

eggs are simply zip files under another name so they are imported using `zipimport.zipimporter` which (unfortunately) is a module written in C.

I think your options are:

1. rewrite a modified zipimporter to accept a `file` like object
   instead of a filename
2. re-implement zipimporter in Python and then
   modify to accept a `file`-like object
3. or write a temporary file to
   disk, import that and then delete the file.

The last of these is probably the easiest.

Comment: Writing to desk is, unfortunately, not an option. I think reimplementing it might be an option.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `imp` module: http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html

You may have some luck with byte-compiled modules or dynamically formed modules.

Also this recipe can probably help (not as is, I guess):

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/82234-importing-a-dynamically-generated-module/

As mentioned, in a comment to the latter, works with single modules only.

The question is similar to one asked some time ago: [Python, import string of Python code as module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614537/python-import-string-of-python-code-as-module)

Answer (score -1):

I am not familiar with Python eggs, but try using a [StringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#StringIO.StringIO) object. Because Python uses [duck typing](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing), you can treat it just like a file if you don't call any file specific methods on it.