# How to run python code from a zip archive

Tags: python

I have a python file inside a zip archive which I want to run directly from a python notebook. Better yet, I'd prefer if I could import from it.

So far I have this:

```
import zipfile

with zipfile.ZipFile('archive.zip', mode='r') as zf:
    with zf.open('code.py') as f:
        # what now?
```

I suppose I could save the file somewhere then import from it. Maybe even using `tempfile` so I can clean up right away (hmm now that I try to implement `tempfile`, it doesn't feel so straight forward). But just wondering if I don't know what I don't know.

Comment: Can you use eval? https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval  - although this may be considered bad practice

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614537/python-import-string-of-python-code-as-module Perhaps importing the string like in this question.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html - This looks like it might be able to import the zips directly. This article seems to imply that you should be able to just use the import syntax to import the zip, double check though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation on zipimport (https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipimport.html) it looks like you can just reference the file you need to use within the zip like so: -

> Examples
> Here is an example that imports a module from a ZIP archive - note that the zipimport > module is not explicitly used.

```
$ unzip -l example.zip
Archive:  example.zip
  Length     Date   Time    Name
 --------    ----   ----    ----
     8467  11-26-02 22:30   jwzthreading.py
 --------                   -------
     8467                   1 file
$ ./python
Python 2.3 (#1, Aug 1 2003, 19:54:32)
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.insert(0, 'example.zip')  # Add .zip file to front of path
>>> import jwzthreading
>>> jwzthreading.__file__
'example.zip/jwzthreading.py'
```

There's some more complex examples in this article here

https://pymotw.com/2/zipimport/

```
import zipimport

importer = zipimport.zipimporter('zipimport_example.zip')
code = importer.get_code('zipimport_get_code')
print code
```

Comment: Nice! It's funny when you think you're the only one crazy enough to need some particular functionality then it turns out to be native. And +1 for the other example which helps me avoid messing up my path which contains clashing file names